# ListIterator allocation in Java

Tags: java, android, for-loop, foreach, iterator

I have a real-time program that runs a continuous while loop...

example:

```
while(true)
{


}
```

Inside that loop I have a `for(MyObject o: myobjects)` loop. When I run my code I see that every iteration of the while loop a new iterator is created to loop over my LinkedList called `myobjects`

What is a better way of iterating over a LinkedList without having Java create a ListIterator every time?

Answer (score 1):

New iterator is given out by design. Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator(int)). It gives you a new iterator every time you call iterator() method and it doesn't maintain states.

Code for the iterator :

```
public ListIterator<E> listIterator(final int index) {
    rangeCheckForAdd(index);

    return new ListItr(index);
}
```

Comment: From my understanding of how LinkedLists work under the hood, why not just maintain a single pointer called 'traverse' for example, and assign it to the 'head' node at the beginning and when it reaches the 'tail' node, stop iterating, then repeat that process... in other words, why re create the 'traverse' pointer every time?

Comment: You can maintain the state. But they can't maintain it for you. Think about it if you want to traverse though a list  to find all duplicates in it? how would you do that if your iterator was maintained by internal code ?

Answer (score 1):

> What is a better way of iterating over a LinkedList without having Java create a ListIterator every time?

"Better" is very situational.  You should consider whether the behavior you have now is actually a problem, because what you describe is about the simplest Java code for the job.

If you do need to iterate specifically over a `LinkedList` (as opposed, say, to an `ArrayList`), and you want to do so without creating a new `ListIterator` every time, then your best bet is probably to create a single `ListIterator` up front, and reuse it at every iteration:

```
ListIterator<MyObject> iterator = myobjects.listIterator();

while (true) {
    // Return to the beginning of the list:
    while (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
        iterator.previous();
    }

    // The desired iteration:
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        MyObject o = iterator.next();
        // do something with o
    }
}
```

Do be aware, however, that this opens you up to trouble if the underlying list is modified.  Any such modification will invalidate the `ListIterator` (its methods should start throwing `ConcurrentModificationException`s).  In your original code, that will affect just one iteration of the outer loop, but if you reuse the iterator then you may need different handling of that situation.  If the list is modified elsewhere in the outer loop, then re-using the same iterator is right out.

On the other hand, if you could be sure that you have a `RandomAccess` list, such as an `ArrayList`, then you could reasonably avoid iterators altogether, and just iterate by index:

```
while (true) {

    // The desired iteration:
    for (int i = 0; i < myobjects.size(); i += 1) {
        MyObject o = myobjects.get(i);
        // do something with o
    }
}
```

Do not do that if you have or may have a `LinkedList`, however, because it will increase the cost of the iteration from O(n) to O(n<sup>2</sup>) for `LinkedList`s and similar sequential-access lists.

Answer (score 0):

The source code of LinkedList says a new iterator is being created. If your list is dynamic, you will need a new iterator as it will become stale.

But, I believe if your list is a constant, you are better off running a normal for loop.

```
`int length = myobjects.size();
 for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
 {
      //access here
 }`
```